# How do I combine 2 sql rows to make single result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a report for someone's poorly designed database and can't figure out how to handle this situation.  This is in MSSQL. I searched for an answer to what I needed and couldn't find this scenario.  When I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
  a.episode, 
  a.SUL, 
  b.element 
FROM TableA as a
  LEFT JOIN TableB as b ON (a.ElementKey = b.ElementKey)
WHERE a.episode = '99999'
```

It returns results that look like this:

```
| episode | SUL | element |
|---------|-----|---------|
| 99999   | 0   | SLC     |
| 99999   | 1   | SL 1    |
```

I need them to look like:

```
| episode | substation | team |
|---------|------------|------|
| 99999   | SLC        | SL1  |
```

The database basically has 2 records for each record. 1 that has a SUL = 0 (with a element name) and 1 with a SUL = 1 with a (with a team name).  I've tried joins and groupBy's and case statements, but nothing that gets me what I need.  Thanks!

Edit:  More information.

TABLE A:

```
| Name       | Type   |
|------------|--------|
| episode    | bigint |
| SUL        | int    |
| elementKey | bigint |
```

Table B:

```
| Name       | Type    |
|------------|---------|
| elementKey | bigint  |
| element    | varchar |
```

I didn't do a good job of explaining.  Basically every 'episode' on 'Table A' will have 2 rows. One with a SUL = 0 and one with SUL = 1.  If it is equal to 0 then I get the 'Table B' element and assign it as 'Substation'.  If it is equal to 1 then I get the 'Table B' element and assign it as 'Team'

Comment: Look for `Pivot`/`Conditional Aggregate`

Comment: I don't believe you've provided enough information to successfully answer the question.  We'll need to see what TableA and TableB look like to know.  E.g.:  Which table is "substation" from?  What does it look like?

Comment: Select episode,substation=max(case when sul=0 then element else null),team =max(case when sul=1 then element else null) From [SomeTable] Group By episode Order By 1

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to add more detail.